# Vuetify dialog adds new dialog to dom each time it is opened and exon't remove the previous on close

Tags: vue.js, dialog, vuetify.js

We have a large scale application but in Vue 2, Composition API and Nuxt.

However we load a lot of content in dialogs. After using the application for several minutes you can see a build up of these dialogs in the DOM.

Is there a way for Vuetify to use the existing dialog one instead of creating a new instance.
Or remove the existing one on close?

I can't see anything in the docs or similar issues from other users.

[image: Multiple dialogs on the dom]

Comment: A v-dialog class element will appears in the dom for each one you included in your template. When you show a specific v-dialog, the class v-dialog-active will be added to it, but a new element is'n added with a normal implementation.

Comment: this isn't true - if you open and close the same dialog it won't re-add a new item to the dom. However if you open and close several different dialogs in the app it will add a new item to the DOM each time. There doesn't seem to be any way you can add a unique id or class to the added DOM elements.

Comment: This isn't true. And  you can check what I explained in this codepen: https://codepen.io/jssDev-/pen/wvrJbBG  Could you show your example?

Comment: If you look at the image you can see the duplicated modal. And like I said I can't recreate this issue in codepen.

Comment: No. At the image I can see three v-dialog-content elements, that might corresponding to three different modals. if you have no way to recreate the problem, it is probably not strictly related to vuejs or vuetify. It could be that any other script in your application is interfering with the operation of this v-dialog component.

Comment: the first and last div with role document is the same modal.

Answer (score 2):

Each `v-dialog` with a `v-model` will be added to the DOM first time it's active/opened, then the visibility is changed on subsequent toggles. It's more "expensive" to add and remove DOM elements (size depending on its nested content) than toggle an active class and add a simple overlay. Probably why it's not recommended to nest `v-dialog` within a `v-for` loop, the DOM will get too crowded. If the dialog content is interchangeable, you could have one dialog on the page where the content is toggled too.